# How can I count task completion date given a number of factors

Tags: sql, postgresql

I could not solve this problem myself. What is needed:

1. We get the creation date and time of one case `(example '01-01-2020 00:00:00'::timestamp)`, as well as the second parameter, we get the number of hours to solve the case `(example '01:00:00'::interval)`.
2. We make calculations:

   - Add up the creation date of case and the time to complete the task, given that working hours are from 7-12 and 13-17 (lunch is 12-13) and weekends are not working days.
3. We get the date and time until which the task should be closed
4. Compare the received date and time with the current

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION support.f_return_tablo_overdue_task(
var_timestamp timestamp,
var_interval interval)
RETURNS timestamp 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
var_current_timestamp TIMESTAMP := now()::timestamp; 
var_when_task_finishes TIMESTAMP; 
BEGIN

RETURN var_when_task_finishes < var_current_timestamp;

END;

$BODY$;
```

I will be very greatfull for all your help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION support.f_return_tablo_overdue_task(
    var_timestamp   timestamp without time zone,
    var_interval    interval)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
    var_current_timestamp   TIMESTAMP := now()::timestamp;  -- Хранит текущую дату и время (без часового пояса) 
    var_time_has_passed     INTERVAL;                       -- Хранит в себе дату и время когда задача должна быть закрыта
BEGIN

    WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        tsrange(var_timestamp, var_current_timestamp) AS working_time,
        tsrange(period_day::timestamp + '08:00', period_day::timestamp + '17:00') working_days, -- Рабочее время (день)
        tsrange(period_day::timestamp + '12:00', period_day::timestamp + '13:00') lunch         -- Перерыв на обед
    FROM generate_series(var_timestamp::date, now()::date, '1 day') period_day
    WHERE extract(isodow FROM period_day) < 6
        AND period_day <> all('{2020-01-01,2020-01-02,2020-01-03,2020-01-04,2020-01-05,2020-01-08,2020-02-23,2020-02-24,2020-03-08,2020-03-09,2020-05-01,2020-05-04,
                              2020-05-05,2020-05-09,2020-05-11,2020-06-12,2020-11-04,2020-12-31}')
    )
    SELECT (sum(upper(hours) - lower(hours)) - sum(upper(lunch_hours) - lower(lunch_hours))) AS hours
    INTO var_time_has_passed
    FROM cte, 
        tsrange(working_days * working_time) AS hours, 
        tsrange(working_days * lunch) AS lunch_hours;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Прошло времени -> %', var_time_has_passed;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Времени в задаче -> %', var_interval;

    RETURN var_time_has_passed > var_interval;

END;
$BODY$;
```